# Проблема при получении конструктора

Tags: javascript, объекты, конструктор

Дан объект constructors. Каждому ключу в нем сопоставлен конструктор класса. Вопрос: почему неправильно исполняется кусок кода(ошибка `source[ch] isn't a constructor`), похожий на это:

```
function elFromChar(source={},ch){
if(!ch||ch==" ")
return null
let obj=new source[ch]();
obj.origCh=ch;
return obj
}
//...
function MyClass(){
//...
}
//...
let constructors={
"mc":MyClass
}
//Some code
console.log(elFromChar(constructors,"mc"))
```

Comment: в последней строке забыли 's'. в таких случаях удобно использовать console.log: сразу видно, где null, где не тот объект.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов, даже с "s" не работает. Выдаёт :"source[ch] is not a constructor"

Comment: у меня теперь так ругается: obj.method(...args) ReferenceError: args is not defined

Comment: Попробуйте теперь

Comment: заработало. выводит: MyClass { origCh: 'mc' }

Comment: У меня не работает

Comment: Ошибка нашлась,была в другой части кода